# While statement causing code to not get executed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

My while statement I have set up is causing my code underneath it to not be executed.

When I use this code here:

```
while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;

            publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

        }
```

to update the progress dialog bar for the file download, my other code I need to have doesn't get executed.

I'm not sure why this is behaving the way it is, if someone could explain and help, that would be great.

Full code:

```
public class SetWallpaperAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
private Context context;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String image_url;
URL mImageUrl;
String myFileUrl1;
Bitmap bmImg = null;

public SetWallpaperAsync(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPreExecute();

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    pDialog.setMessage("Downloading Image...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
pDialog.setMax(100);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    InputStream is = null;

    int count;

    try {

        mImageUrl = new URL(args[0]);
        // myFileUrl1 = args[0];

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) mImageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        int lenghtOfFile = conn.getContentLength();
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;



        while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;

            publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

        }


        //This code doesn't get executed when using the code above
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
        bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {

        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

    pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (bmImg == null) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Image still loading...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

    else {

        WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
        try {
            wpm.setBitmap(bmImg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        pDialog.dismiss();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Wallpaper Successfully Set!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Didn't catch it - what is publishProgress() ?

Comment: @Jack  why need to read the bytes of stream as you are not assigning bytes to any other? directly you can get InputStream and pass that Stream to BitmapFactory....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop consumes all input there is i.e. until `-1` end-of-stream is reached.

When you try to decode a bitmap from the same stream here:

```
bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
```

... there's nothing to decode.

Comment: Would cloning input streams be a good idea or not to achieve this? or would there be another way to do it?

Comment: @Jack Use a progress-aware input stream, i.e. subclass the stream class and override `read` to post notifications on progress.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is some exception in the loop:

```
while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;

            publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

        }
```

that is causing the rest of the code for not being executed.

Check in the `catch statement` if there is some **exception** or debug for the code flow to identify the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the maximum progress to content length...

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    ..........
    final int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pDialog.setMax(contentLength);
        }
    });
    .........
}
```

Comment: his question is misleading. I too thought his complaint was that progress updates weren't being displayed but while reading his code, I spotted that he comments the problem is that what _follows_ the while loop isn't running -- I assume `bmImg` is never getting set from his complaint.

Comment: @mah let us see Jack reply to this answer... actually he is calling publishProgress() in while loop. here progress will be 1024 when while loop executes for first time...

Comment: The while loop is running. When using the while code, the code under it doesn't get executed for some odd reason

Comment: Make sure your URL is returning the response. Your loop is correct. either  while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) or  while ((count = is.read(data)) >0 ) should work fine.

Comment: @Jack why need to read the bytes of stream as you are not assigning bytes to any other? directly you can get InputStream and pass that Stream to BitmapFactory...